# How to use Hive with a Switch in Flutter- so when back is clicked the switch is still activated?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have just recently added Hive to my Flutter project already intiallized it and added the needed dependencies,

now I am trying to get a way to use the Hive database for the settings menu of my App ,
for a switch when its turned on and user clicks back button I still want it to remain off and when user has it turned off it remains off, I have 8 switches on the page

please help:

```
 activateHeartHighlighter(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _heartColor = true;
      _heartSwitch = true;
      _heartEnable = true;
      _icymistColor = false;
      _icymistSwitch = false;
      _icymistEnable = true;
      _deepoceanColor = false;
      _deepoceanSwitch = false;
      _deepoceanEnable = true;
      _flowerColor = false;
      _flowerSwitch = false;
      _flowerEnable = true;
      _gardenColor = false;
      _gardenSwitch = false;
      _gardenEnable = true;
      _paradiseColor = false;
      _paradiseSwitch = false;
      _paradiseEnable = true;
      _midnightparadiseColor = false;
      _midnightparadiseSwitch = false;
      _midnightparadisEnable = true;
      _midnightColor = false;
      _midnightEnable = true;
      _midnightSwitch = false;
      // if (activateIcyMistHighlighter(value)) {
      //   setState(() {
      //     // _heartColor = false;
      //   });
    }
        // }
        );
  }




@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return Scaffold(
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: Hive.box('settings').listenable(),
        builder: (context, box, widget) {
          return Switch(
              value: box.get(_heartSwitch),
              onChanged: (_heartSwitch) {
                box.put(_heartSwitch, _heartColor);
                return Scaffold(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    // Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
                    appBar: AppBar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
                        title: Text("Settings Menu",
                            style: TextStyle(color: styling.appBarTextcolor)),



  Switch(
                                      // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                      value: _heartSwitch,
                                      activeColor: Colors.red,
                                      // title: Text("final one"),

                                      onChanged: (bool _heartColor) =>
                                          activateHeartHighlighter(
                                              _heartColor)),
                                  // ),
```

Comment: Your code is screaming for about 8 objects with three members each.  Hint: if you have many variables with similar names... they belong in some structure.

Comment: I am new to this, how would you re write this logic?